# 24-bit Binary to single precision floating point number

Tags: floating-point, binary

I have the following 24-bit binary:

> 0101 0011 1111 1101 0111 1101

And I need to figure out:

> What pair of single precision floating point (real) numbers could be represented by these 24-bits?

The text book example is saying that splitting the 24 bits into two 12-bit binary numbers is the direction I should head.

I'd end up with `0101 0011 1111` & `1101 0111 1101`

However my problem is, my text book only gives an actual working example of 16 and 32 bit binary numbers. I'm unsure of how to figure out the exponent, mantissa, characteristic. It's all very new to me.

edit: Here is an excerpt from the text book indicating what I should be achieving:

> For example, the string of 24-bits:
>
> 0011 0110 0011 1001 0011 0101
>
> Converted to a pair of single precision floating point (real) numbers 0.13672 and −0.0004044.
>
> Any single precision floating point (real) number between 0.13672 and 0.1406 will have the same 12-bit pattern, in this not very accurate computer.

For those who found this question confusing: How did the textbook convert `0011 0110 0011 1001 0011 0101` to 0.13672 and −0.0004044?

Comment: How can **a pair** of "single precision floating point (real) numbers" be represented by the same 24 bits?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I dont know haha, thats why I'm asking. I'm quite confused. I'm assuming it's saying to split the 24-bits into 2 x 12-bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the 24-bit value into a pair of 12-bit fields looks like the right approach.  For the two 12-bit fields the floating-point format used here appears to be, starting at the leftmost bit:

- one sign bit (0 for positive, 1 for negative)
- five exponent bits, giving an unsigned value that is biased by 15 (so we must subtract 15 from the unsigned value of this field to get the actual exponent)
- six bits of significand giving an unsigned value

The absolute value of a floating-point number expressed in this format will be given by:

```
significand * ( 2 ^ exponent ) / ( 2 ^ 6 )
```

For the given examples, we have:

```
0011 0110 0011 =>
  sign bit       = 0, positive
  exponent field = 01101, which is decimal 13, so actual exponent = 13 - 15 = -2
  significand    = 100011, which is decimal 35

  value = positive 35 * ( 2 ^ -2 ) / ( 2 ^ 6 ) = 0.13672

1001 0011 0101 =>
  sign bit       = 1, negative
  exponent field = 00100, which is decimal 4, so actual exponent = 4 - 15 = -11
  significand    = 110101, which is decimal 53

  value = negative 53 * ( 2 ^ -11 ) / ( 2 ^ 6 ) = -0.0004044
```

You can confirm the commentary about the precision of this format by repeating these calculations with significand values that have been incremented by one.

Comment: Awesome thank you! My issue was my textbook taught me how to do this on 16, 32, and 64bit binaries. How did you know to use 5 for the exponent? Can you recommend any further resources?